# Recover bootloader with failed signature verification

Tags: 8.1, samsung-ativ-s

I bricked my phone :(

I removed the battery during early boot up, now the bootup stops with a text-mode error screen.

[image: screenshot of boot error]

I can not insert a CD in my phone, nor do i have an enter or windows key.

A hard reset was also unsuccessful.

Do I have options left other than "dump the brick and get a new phone with which to be more careful"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unlike Microsoft / Nokia there is no official recovery tool for the Samsung ATIV S to flash your OS. You might find an unofficial way to flash your phone - guess there's not much you can break.

Still, Samsung Service should be able to repair your phone, though I'm not sure if that's covered by the warranty.